# XmlSerde error in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
While trying to execute the create table statement in hive getting the below error.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE BOOKDATA(
    >   TITLE VARCHAR(40),
    >    PRICE  INT
    >    )ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
    >    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    >    "column.xpath.TITLE"="/CATALOG/BOOK/TITLE/",
    >    "column.xpath.PRICE"="/CATALOG/BOOK/PRICE/")
    >    STORED AS
    >    INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    >    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    >    LOCATION '/sourcedata'
    >    TBLPROPERTIES (
    >    "xmlinput.start"="<CATALOG",
    >    "xmlinput.end"= "</CATALOG>"
    >    );
```

**FAILED: SemanticException Cannot find class 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'**

Please help on how to resolve this issue.I am using hive CLI.

Comment: Did you add the rellevant jar?

Comment: When i add each time on the hive session its running fine. How do i add it permanently, so that when i start the hive session it ivokes this jar automatically.(fyi, i am using mapr sandbox)? ( i have tried the option of placing the serde jar into the lib folder and refereing that path in hive-site.xml ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-QueryandDDLExecution

1.

Requires restart of HiveServer2

> **hive.aux.jars.path**
>   - Default Value: (empty)
>   - Added In: Hive 0.2.0 or earlier
>   The location of the plugin jars that contain implementations
>   of user defined functions (UDFs) and SerDes.

2.

> **hive.reloadable.aux.jars.path**
>   - Default Value: (empty)
>   - Added In: Hive 0.14.0 with HIVE-7553
>    The locations of the plugin jars, which can be comma-separated folders or jars. They can be renewed (added, removed,
>   or updated) by executing the Beeline reload command without having to
>   restart HiveServer2. These jars can be used just like the auxiliary
>   classes in hive.aux.jars.path for creating UDFs or SerDes.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced a similar issue in past. What worked out for me is just changing the hive engine to tez.

set hive.execution.engine=tez;

When you set Tez engine, It will pick up all the jars it needs to run a query.

Let me know if that works out for you.